# Phone number and Google+ account

Tags: contacts, google-hangouts

Google recently updated Hangouts so that SMS and hangout are in the Same chat. Some of my contacts have multiple email with multiple Google plus accounts. My issue is that it randoms picked the account and they aren't the accounts I want them to be. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just split the contact up in two? so if the account have two Google accounts it is just two contacts on your address book. 
It looks to me that you are only able to choose between more numbers, so if your contacts have multiple phone numbers you can choose between them, but emails you aren't. (even when they are added as Hangout emails and is a verified Google+ account.) 
The way i would do it is split them up in multiple contacts and then make a group chat with that person that have more then one Google account.

Comment: Not really the whole point was to unified it if I did that is it not defeating the purpose